# Upgrade to CSLA 6: ConnectionManager problem

Tags: csla

we are trying to upgrade to CSLA 6.
now, we are getting a message:
*"ConnectionManager is obsolete, use dependency injection ...  use  ApplicationContext.LocalContext"*

```
for this code:

 using (var ctx = ConnectionManager<OracleConnection>.GetManager("dbEndpoint", true))
```

We've tried this code snippet but all connections is NULL.
Could you please help us to correctly get Connection?

```
   var services = new ServiceCollection();
   services.AddCsla();
    
   var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    
   DataPortalFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<IDataPortalFactory>();
   var appContext = provider.GetRequiredService<Csla.ApplicationContext>();
    
    
var conn1 = appContext.LocalContext.GetValueOrNull("dbEndpoint");
var conn2 = appContext.LocalContext.GetValueOrNull("__db:default-dbEndpoint");
    
var conn3 = appContext.LocalContext["dbEndpoint"];
var conn4 = appContext.LocalContext["__db:default-dbEndpoint"];
```

another experiment:

```
....
                var CONNECTION_ORACLE = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbEndpoint"].ConnectionString);

                services.AddScoped<IDbConnection>(o => CONNECTION_ORACLE);
....
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
...
var connectionResolved = provider.GetRequiredService<IDbConnection>();

                appContext.LocalContext.Add("dbEndpoint", connectionResolved);
```

then connection is not null;

and inside of Factory is successfully resolved by DI:

```
public DocFactory(ApplicationContext appContext, IDbConnection connection) : base(
    appContext)
{
    _connection = connection;
}
```

then

```
[Fetch]
public Doc_Fetch(DocCriteria criteria)
{
    bool cancel = false;
    OnFetching(criteria, ref cancel);
    if (cancel) return null;

    Doc item = null;

    OracleConnection connection = _connection as OracleConnection;
```

connection is Closed (but **NOT null**!!). it's possible to open it but if close it, somebody else consuming it will face with a problem or child objects also will face problem with closed connection.
so, making ConnectionManager as Obsolete may be not so obvious way to go. But ConnectionManager was very useful for **counting open connection, supporting transactions** etc
Could you please provide a workaround for it.
more attempts:

```
var connectionString = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbEndpoint"].ConnectionString;
..
 appContext.ClientContext.Add("DBConnectionString", connectionString );
...
Factory
           using (var connection = new OracleConnection(ApplicationContext.ClientContext["DBConnectionString"].ToString()))

            {
                connection.Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DAL should require that a database connection be injected.

```cs
public class MyDal : IDisposable
{
  public MyDal(OracleConnection connection)
  {
    Connection = connection;
  }

  private OracleConnection Connection { get; set; }

  public MyData GetData()
  {
    // use Connection to get the data
    return data;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Connection.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Then in the app server startup code, register your DAL type(s) and also register your connection type.

```cs
  services.AddScoped(typeof(OracleConnection), () =>
    {
      // initialize the connection here
      return connection;
    });
  services.AddScoped<MyDal>();
```

Then, in your data portal operation method (such as create, fetch, etc.), inject your DAL:

```cs
  [Fetch]
  private void Fetch([Inject] MyDal dal)
  {
    var data = dal.GetData();
  }
```

Comment: the workaround you suggested doesn't resolve problem with reusable connections and child-parent requests and transactions.
"Old" ConnectionManager, that is "obsolete" now was counting Refs (AddRef, DeRef methods). Correctly supports transactions etc.
What kind of class in the newest CSLA 6 supports the same functionaluty?
1) It looks like every developer should now create the own version of "old" ConnectionManager to counting Refs etc?

Comment: 2) you have some samples for CSLA 6.
But you always run against in-memory collection as DataSource.
Could you update your samples to run against, for example, SqlLite(so no needs to have "real" database to be installed)?
then it will be more understable what is modern approach to use transactions, connections,counting connections etc.

Comment: 3) Would be great option to make this ConnectionManager also DI-friendly it means to make IConnectionManager interface?
Then by default when we call services.AddCsla() it will register "standard" ConnectionManager as impelementation of IConnectionManager. Somebody could provide another impelementation of it.

Comment: Discussions of updates/features/changes to CSLA should occur in the GitHub repo discussion area: https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/discussions